# Jenkins Release job vs Build Job

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson, release

I have very basic question. What are the differences if somebody says that I have a release job to run in jenkins VS I have a build job to run in Jenkins. What actually Release job do and what does the Build job do?

Comment: I guess both are same

Answer (score 2):

Releases are a special type of build enabled by the [Release plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Release+Plugin).

> [The Release] plugin adds the ability to wrap your job with pre- and post- build steps which are only executed when a manual release build is triggered.

The Release plugin is useful when you want to use the same job for continuous integration as for some other publishing steps that are triggered manually. We use the Release plugin to have a special sequence of steps to publish artifacts and create a tag when we want to make a release build that gets published to QA.

Comment: Is there a way to identify whether the build is a release build or a normal build inside the prebuild script at jenkins?